# Android, Fragment и Moxy

Tags: android, android-fragment, fragment-transaction, fragment-manager, moxy

Имеется следующий код, фрагменты `extends MvpPresenter<OneFragmentView>`.

```
private OneFragment oneFragment = null;
private TwoFragment twoFragment = null;

private void setFragment(int layoutId) {
    FragmentTransaction fTrans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    MvpAppCompatFragment fragment = null;

    switch (layoutId) {
        case R.layout.fragment_two:
            twoFragment = twoFragment == null ? new TwoFragment() : twoFragment;
            fragment = twoFragment;
            break;
        case R.layout.fragment_one:
            oneFragment = oneFragment == null ? new OneFragment() : oneFragment;
            fragment = oneFragment;
            break;
    }

    fTrans.replace(R.id.home_fragment_container, fragment).commit();
}
```

При переключении с одного фрагмента на другой, каждый раз создается новый Presenter и пропадает состояние фрагмента.

Помогает `fTrans.addToBackStack(null);` и Presenter не пересоздается. Но сразу возникает следующая проблема:

К примеру я перехожу с OneFrag -> TwoFrag -> OneFrag -> TwoFrag, а после нажимаю на кнопку назад и что бы выйти из приложения получается обратный переход по фрагментам: OneFrag -> TwoFrag -> OneFrag -> exit.

Как сделать так, что бы фрагменты переключались без пересоздания Presenter во фрагментах?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для такого вам следует делать глобальный презентер. В `Moxy` есть аннотация `@ProvidePresenter(type = PresenterType.GLOBAL)`. Но в этом есть один минус,  вы должны передать `MvpDelegate` информацию, по которой он сможет найти нужный вам Presenter в хранилище всех Presenter. Примеры здесь: [хабр](https://habr.com/post/276189/) и [документация](https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy/wiki/Provides-Presenter-and-its-Tag)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. А правильно ли это? Делать глобальный Presenter для фрагментов?

Comment: Скорее нет, чем да. Тут все зависит от конкретного кейса. Также можно например сделать какой либо репозиторий для хранения состояние, а презентеры пересоздавать. Подходов много.